# C++ How to access data member of an object returned from a function?

Tags: c++, avl-tree

I have the following code which simply checks an AVL tree if a word/key already exist in it. If it does it returns a pointer to that node otherwise it returns null:

```
void fileInput::testFunction() {
    node newWord;
    newWord.key = "test";
    newWord.wordCount = 1;
    tree.AVL_Insert(newWord);
    if ((verifyWord("test").wordCount) != NULL) {
        //insert increment wordCount code here;
    }
}
```

This is the node struct:

```
struct node {
    string key;
    int wordCount;
};
```

This is verifyWord function

```
node fileInput::verifyWord(string a) {
    node b;
    tree.AVL_Retrieve(a, b);
    return b;
}
```

This is the AVL_Retreive function:

```
template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
bool   AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>
   ::  AVL_Retrieve  (KTYPE   key, TYPE& dataOut)
{
    NODE<TYPE> *node;

    if (!tree)
       return false;

    node    = _retrieve (key, tree);
    if (node)
       {
        dataOut = node->data;
        return true;
       } // if found
    else
       return false;
}   //  AVL_Retrieve
```

My question is how would i be able to increment wordCount of the returned object inside the if statement in testFunction()

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: "I would like to check if a word already exist in the tree if it does i would like to increment its wordCount otherwise i would insert it to the tree" -- sounds like a good plan. Give it your best try, then let us know how it works out.

Comment: @JohnZwinck How can i increment wordCount in the object pointer returned by verifyWord function

Comment: @nanjero05 verifyWord does not return an object pointer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the code in every one of your functions so that `AVL_Retrieve()` returns a pointer to the node if it is found, or NULL if not found.  Then `verifyWord()` will return the very same pointer.  Then you can use that pointer to modify the node.  Something like this:

```
if (node* nn = verifyWord("test")) {
    nn->wordCount++;
}

node* fileInput::verifyWord(string a) {
    return tree.AVL_Retrieve(a);
}

template <class TYPE, class KTYPE>
TYPE* AvlTree<TYPE, KTYPE>
   ::  AVL_Retrieve  (KTYPE   key)
{
    if (!tree)
       return NULL;

    if (NODE<TYPE> *node = _retrieve (key, tree))
        return node->data;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```